# StoredProcedure In EntityFramework DateTime Error

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, stored-procedures, frameworks

In my project i have used EntityFramework 5 and I came up to use an SP in my Context. Like this

```
public virtual object GetEvaluations(int AgentId, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, int FormId)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (DbDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand = _context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "GetEvaluations";

        SqlParameter aid = new SqlParameter("@AgentId", SqlDbType.Int);
        aid.Value = AgentId;
        SqlParameter sd = new SqlParameter("@StartDate", StartDate.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        SqlParameter ed = new SqlParameter("@EndDate", EndDate.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy"));
        SqlParameter fid = new SqlParameter("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int);
        fid.Value = FormId;

        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(aid);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(sd);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(ed);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(fid);

        adapter.Fill(table);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Here the DateTime formats different style but just working like this. Even this 2 parameters are looking to the same field in the table.

Please look at datetime formats (they are different) i think they must be same style.

My SP:

```
USE [EvaluationAssistt]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetEvaluations]    Script Date: 12.03.2015 11:25:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Hammit Yildirim
-- Create date: 11.03.2015
-- Description: Defined for Category Point Reports Performance
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEvaluations]-- 258,'1.11.2014','11.24.2014',8
@AgentId int,
@StartDate Datetime,
@EndDate Datetime,
@FormId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select fce.Id from FormsCallsEvaluated fce
        left join FormsCalls fc on fce.CallId = fc.CallId
        where fc.AgentId=@AgentId and fc.DateStarted > @StartDate and fc.DateStarted < @EndDate and fce.FormId=@FormId
END
```

What is my problem

I tryed below and returning me empty table

```
 public virtual object GetEvaluations(int AgentId, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, int FormId)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (DbDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand = _context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "GetEvaluations";

            SqlParameter aid = new SqlParameter("@AgentId", SqlDbType.Int);
            aid.SqlValue = AgentId;
            SqlParameter sd = new SqlParameter("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sd.SqlValue = StartDate.Date;
            SqlParameter ed = new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            ed.SqlValue = EndDate.Date;
            SqlParameter fid = new SqlParameter("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int);
            fid.SqlValue = FormId;

            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(aid);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(sd);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(ed);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(fid);

            adapter.Fill(table);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

It is working SQL side just like this

```
USE [EvaluationAssistt]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetEvaluations]
        @AgentId = 258,
        @StartDate = N'1.11.2014',
        @EndDate = N'11.24.2014',
        @FormId = 8

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: What is the error message exactly? On which line? What is the definition of your `GetEvaluations` sp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined your `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` columns as `DateTime` but you try to pass them string values.

Just pass the right type and values to your parameter like;

```
SqlParameter sd = new SqlParameter("@StartDate", StartDate.Date);
SqlParameter ed = new SqlParameter("@EndDate", EndDate.Date);
```

Comment: @JenishRabadiya On where exactly? He defines it's parameter in `where fc.AgentId=@AgentId and fc.DateStarted > @StartDate and fc.DateStarted < @EndDate and fce.FormId=@FormId` ?

Comment: Soner i tryed this style firstly but this is gave me empty table not a result set

Comment: @SonerGönül `adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "GetEvaluations";` doesn't it required to be `adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "GetEvaluations @AgentId @StartDate...";` so

Comment: @JenishRabadiya No. I never heard such a thing. Since it's a `StoredProcedure`, it just need to sp name as a `CommandText`, nothing more.

Comment: @HamitYıldırım Did you debug your code line by line and check command after you add  parameter values? It gets data when you try it on SSMS?

Comment: @SonerGonul yes i have tryed its getting right value even i looked on SqlProfiller it is apearing with the right value. is it maybe interesting Database Collation

Comment: it is working on sql side like just this parameters. I have edited my question look just last snipt

Comment: Ok I have solved this problem and the blame is mine. If i have call with this parameters '11.01.2014' (MM.dd.yyyy) and '24.11.2014' (dd.MM.yyyy) SqlServer returning one years records interesting 2014 i think this is unknown behavior. But if i write same format both like dd.MM.yyyy it is returning right result if exist. Thank you all